# XMLWriter issues in C#

Tags: c#, xml, directory

My issue is that I can't have the XML's file name be saved based on the text of a given field: here is the line:

```
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(@"{0}\ops\op-" + OpName.Text.Replace(" ", "_") + ".xml", 
                                         System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

The issue I get is that it can't find the path: `C:\[stuff]\{0}\op\op-.xml` and if I remove the `{0}`(in the code) I get `can't find C:\op\op-.xml`

I am needing it to find `C:\[stuff]\op\` so it can make the file in that folder.

How could I change this line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does `{0}` represents in your path? `XmlTextWriter` constructor takes file path, not a formatted string. It would be much more readable if you'd prepare your file path in steps, eg. by utilizing [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782933.aspx) method:

```
var fileName = string.Format("op-{0}.xml", OpName.Text.Replace(" ", "_"));
var rootDir = /* this would be {0} from your original example */
var filePath = Path.Combine(rootDir, "ops", fileName);

XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(filePath, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: what is `{0}` after the `-` in your solution? and in mine the `{0}` is to get the path so it can find `C:\[stuff]\ops\ ` and save the file there.

Comment: @user1720845 The difference is that both answers are using `String.Format` in which `"{0}"` actually has any meaning, while you are simply using it in a string, which results in the literal `{0}`

Comment: I am not sure what goes in the rootDir= spot, I cant put `@"{0}"` or any variation...

Comment: nvm, I just used `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`

Answer (score 0):

```cs
string additionalStr=OpName.Text.Replace(" ", "_");
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(additionalStr))
{
    return;
    //or throw error or make default file name depending on the required logic
}
string directoryPath=String.Format(@"{0}\ops\",dirPrefix);
bool isDirectoryExists=Directory.Exists(directoryPath);
if (!isDirectoryExists){     
    //required logic. for example set default directory
}
string fileName=additionalStr+".xml";
string filePath=Path.Combine(directoryPath,fileName);
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(filePath,System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: it does not solve the issue of it looking for a folder that does not exist, the {0} is needed for it to not just look for C:\op\op-.xml but the issue is that it is looking for C:\[stuff]\{0}\op\op-.xml and not C:\[stuff]\op\op-.xml. It does not get to be able to try to name the file cause it cant find where to put it.